# Downgrading gcc/relevant packages on Ubuntu Server 16.04.1

Tags: server, apt, 16.04, package-management, gcc

Got a clean install with Ubuntu Server 16.04.1, only having installed whatever that comes along when selecting OpenSSH server during the installation.

I need to install a few more packages in order to use the server as intended; I need dkms, xdm, x11-xserver-utils and a few more. When I try to install these I get errors about unmet dependicies for gcc-5, cpp, and thus I can't get any further.

`sudo apt-get install gcc`

```
gcc : Depends: cpp(>= 4:5.3.1-ubuntu1) but it is not going to be installed.
     Depends: gcc-5 (>= 5.3.1-3~) but is not going to be installed.
```

Now if I try

`sudo apt-get install gcc-5`

```
gcc-5: Depends: cpp-5 (= 5.3.1-14ubuntu2.1) but it is not going to be installed
       Depends: gcc-5-base (= 5.3.1-14ubuntu2.1) but 5.4.0~6ubuntu1~16.04.1 is to be installed
       Depends: libcc1-0 (>= 5.3.1-14ubuntu2.1) but is not going to be installed
       Depends: libgcc-5-dev (= 5.3.1-14ubuntu2.1) but is not going to be installed
```

And it continues like this. I tried `sudo apt-get install gcc-5-base=5.3.1-14ubuntu2.1`, but this required me to uninstall a bunch of stuff.

I don't full overview of the setup here, but the server isn't connected to the internet; there's a local APT-repository I'm redirected to when using `deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/xenial whatever`.

I did the same procedure on another server with the same setup, and there I ended up just downgrading one package without having to uninstall everything else, but since that's a "long time" ago (and I didn't write it down, so yes, stupid as f***), I wonder if anyone can point me in the right direction here.

Regards.
RM.

Comment: The local repository is almost certainly broken in some way. Talk to the people in charge of it. If they can't help you with your problem, they shouldn't be in the business of managing repositories.

Comment: Feared it'd be something like that. I'll ask him when he's back on work. But  until then, there's no way to solve this? E.g. install from the ISO or something like that?

Comment: Ended up making my own very local offline repo to fix this problem. Probably not the best long term solution, but fixed the issue. Problem can be closed/deleted/whatever.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem was solved by making my own repository with `apt-mirror` and syncing against that instead.